# How can I resolve the ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list

Tags: python, pytorch

I received this message after running the optimizer function. The error pops up below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 3
      1 # Define the criterion and optimizer for the quantized model
      2 criterion = nn.MSELoss()
----> 3 optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(quantized_model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\torch\optim\adam.py:33, in Adam.__init__(self, params, lr, betas, eps, weight_decay, amsgrad, foreach, maximize, capturable, differentiable, fused)
     27     raise ValueError("Invalid weight_decay value: {}".format(weight_decay))
     29 defaults = dict(lr=lr, betas=betas, eps=eps,
     30                 weight_decay=weight_decay, amsgrad=amsgrad,
     31                 maximize=maximize, foreach=foreach, capturable=capturable,
     32                 differentiable=differentiable, fused=fused)
---> 33 super().__init__(params, defaults)
     35 if fused:
     36     if differentiable:

File D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\torch\optim\optimizer.py:187, in Optimizer.__init__(self, params, defaults)
    185 param_groups = list(params)
    186 if len(param_groups) == 0:
--> 187     raise ValueError("optimizer got an empty parameter list")
    188 if not isinstance(param_groups[0], dict):
    189     param_groups = [{'params': param_groups}]

ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list
```

There are practically no issues with printing the quantization before and after the dynamics. I am able to print the model in terms of the shape and the details of the model. I stumbled upon the optimization step, in which I keep getting the ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list. I'm unsure of what's causing the problem. Can someone spot the error in the code?

The full code:

```
!pip install torch -U                                                                                   import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.quantization import QuantStub, DeQuantStub
from torch.quantization import quantize_dynamic                                                                  class QuantizedCNNModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
super(QuantizedCNNModel, self).__init__()
self.quant = QuantStub()
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 1)
self.dequant = DeQuantStub()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.quant(x)
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.dequant(x)
        return x                                                                                              quantized_model = QuantizedCNNModel()

quantized_model = quantize_dynamic(quantized_model, {nn.Linear}, dtype=torch.qint8)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(quantized_model.parameters(), lr=0.001)                                            for epoch in range(10):
optimizer.zero_grad()
inputs = torch.randn(32, 512)  
targets = torch.randn(32, 1)  
outputs = quantized_model(inputs)  # Use quantized_model here
loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
torch.save(quantized_model.state_dict(), 'QuantizedCnnModel_cpu.pth')
def inference(input):
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
input = input.to(device)
with torch.no_grad():
output = quantized_model(input)  # Use quantized_model here
return output

sample_input = torch.randn(1, 512)  
output = inference(sample_input)
```